# How do disable the Alt+Tab,Alt+F4,ctr+Alt+Delete buttons from C# program?

Tags: c#

I am Using On application I want  disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> buttons from C# program. And also to disable the right click if the users go at the top and click right it should not come it should not show that menu-bar also. How to do in web application?

Comment: Do I have this right? You want to make a website which prevents the user from changing application, closing the window, killing the browser process or exiting via the menu and no right clicking? Essentially Malware

Comment: I hope you will not find out how to do it.

Comment: @apoorv020 - `how to do in web application`. If you don't want to write malware and you just want to restrict certain machines, you will need to do this through windows.

Comment: @vigna hari karthik: You could create a website that contains so many content, long-running scripts, and complex formatting that it essentially makes the browser non-responsive. If you're lucky, this will even crash the whole machine, and it will be unusable. Goal reached.

Comment: @Downvoters: this is a valid question even if you don't want it on your PC.

Comment: @vigna: Do you want this isn a Web Application or do you want to run a Browser  this way?

Comment: ya i want to control through c# coding for banking application

Comment: banking application??? disable task manager... o la la.. Why do you need it?

Comment: @vigna: Answering a "did you mean A or B" question with "ya" isn't helping.

Comment: This is bad practice, bad precedent and a bad idea.  What if your app crashes in a way that prevents the user any interactivity?  I sure don't want your app plastered in the middle of my screen without a way to close it when it does something you didn't expect.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Kiosk Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kiosk+c%23).

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for a very very good reason. You can't even log it happening.

Comment: You somewhat can disable it. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188951.aspx

Comment: and, after that, you have `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` to accede the Task Manager...

Comment: Well, you can disable it from doing what it normally does, but you can't make the computer ignore it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Ctrl+Alt+Del I think you can set `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DisableTaskMgr` to `1`.

To disable the rest of the keyboard combinations you could probably write a keyboard hook.

This article: [C# Disable CTRL-ALT-DEL, ALT-TAB, ALT-F4, Start Menu and so on…](http://tamaspiros.co.uk/2007/12/20/c-disable-ctrl-alt-del-alt-tab-alt-f4-start-menu-and-so-on/) should show you how to do all this.

I'm not a web guy but I'm assuming that you wouldn't be able to do any of this from the webapp itself so you'd have to:

1. Write a WinForms/Console app.
2. Get the user to download it.
3. Get the user to execute it with Admin rights.

Edit: And if you mean that you want to disable rightclicking to open menus etc in the webbrowser, you'd probably have to create your own webbrowser (possibly you could do this just by hosting the webbrowser control and turning off menus etc).

Comment: Task manager starts with Shift-Ctrl-Esc and not Ctrl-Alt-Del

Comment: you have `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` to accede the Task Manager, but `Ctrl+Alt+Del` also indirectyly can do that...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a web page being displayed in a web browser by using the term **web application**, there is no way to achieve your goal - and that's very good! Imagine the implications if any website I'm calling could disable me from existing the browser and/or changing to another application.

If you want to display just the one website you will have to modify (or configure) the browser itself.